# Fill Down Multiple Cells with Formulas with text string

Tags: vba, excel

I want to ask about vba excel, I want to fill down the formula for multiple cell, but the formula contain text string.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim strFormulas(1 To 2) As Variant

    With ActiveSheet
        strFormulas(1) = "=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Apple,B2))"
        strFormulas(2) = "=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Orange,B2))"

        .Range("C2:D2").Formula = strFormulas
        .Range("C2:D11").FillDown
    End With

End Sub
```

at the first I make it like this, but because the local in there isn't text string, so the result all false, because the formula should be `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Apple",B2))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
strFormulas(1) = "=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Apple"",B2))"
strFormulas(2) = "=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""Orange"",B2))"
```

Comment: ah this one worked, thanks
i try something similar before



strFormulas(1) = "=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Apple",B2))"
strFormulas(2) = "=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Orange",B2))"

can i ask why we need two " instead of one? i'm sorry i still new to VBA Excel

Comment: @OngokOngoksepen you can see here on [how to put quotation mark in a string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/267k4fw5(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Doubling up on the quotes is a simpler solution, but incase you are interested another way to approach it would be to use `Chr(34)`

```
Sub Test()

    Dim strFormulas(1 To 2) As Variant

    With ActiveSheet
        strFormulas(1) = "=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" & Chr(34) & "Apple" & Chr(34) & ",B2))"
        strFormulas(2) = "=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" & Chr(34) & "Orange" & Chr(34) & ",B2))"

        .Range("C2:D2").Formula = strFormulas
        .Range("C2:D11").FillDown
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Ongok, this approach is my favorite.  It guarantees the `Chr(34)` which is the `"` character code gets added.

Comment: thanks mate, really appreciate that you give me another approach